# Clicking 'Accept All' on Cookie Banner at Joyn.de Using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, shadow-dom, webautomation

I am working on a web automation task using Selenium WebDriver with C#, specifically trying to accept the cookies on the "joyn.de" website by clicking the 'Accept All' button in the cookie banner. This button is hidden within a shadow DOM, and I'm having trouble interacting with it. Below is the code snippet I've been working with:

```
   try
                        {
                            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver37, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                            IWebElement shadowHost = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("#__next > cmp-banner")));

                            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver37;
                            string script = "return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('div > div:nth-child(2) > div > cmp-dialog > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > cmp-button > button');";
                            IWebElement acceptButton = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript(script, shadowHost);

                            acceptButton.Click();
                        }
                        catch 
                        {
                          
                        }
```

The goal is to automate clicking the 'Accept All' on the cookie consent banner of joyn.de. I am not sure if my approach is incorrect or if I am missing something crucial for interacting with shadow-root elements. Can anyone provide insights or corrections to help click the button effectively?

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What I tried:

I used Selenium WebDriver with C# to automate interaction with a web page.
My task was to click the 'Accept All' button on the cookie consent banner on joyn.de.
To access the button within the shadow DOM, I used the WebDriverWait to ensure the element is present and then utilized IJavaScriptExecutor to execute a script that navigates through the shadow-root to the specific button.
Here's the specific part of the code designed to find and click the button:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver37, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement shadowHost = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("#__next > cmp-banner")));

IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver37;
string script = "return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('div > div:nth-child(2) > div > cmp-dialog > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > cmp-button > button');";
IWebElement acceptButton = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript(script, shadowHost);

acceptButton.Click();
```

What I was expecting:

The script should navigate through the shadow DOM structure and locate the 'Accept All' button on the cookie consent banner.
Once the button is located, the script should click the button, effectively accepting all cookies and allowing me to automate further interactions on the joyn.de website.
I expected this to happen seamlessly and the cookie consent to be handled without manual intervention, allowing the automation process to proceed.
However, I encountered issues (you would detail any errors or unexpected behaviors here), which is why I am seeking assistance to understand what might be going wrong or if there are alternative approaches to handle shadow DOM elements more effectively in Selenium with C#.